# How to create an own type for a setting in Kivy?

Tags: python, settings, kivy

I'd like to extend a Kivy settings panel to pick a color for some lines / backgrounds etc. for my app.

I've added a new type for a ColorPicker to a Kivy settings panel and it is almost working. But I have the problem that the value of the currently picked color is not displayed in the settings panel. (missing text see red circle in below screenshot)

[image: value text missing]

I think it's a simple problem but I haven't found a fix yet. My Class has the name SettingColorPicker (base class SettingItem) and if I rename it to SettingString and remove the original SettingString class than it works as expected. I don't know why?!

I registered the new type like this:

```
   s = Settings()
   s.register_type('colorpicker', SettingColorPicker)
```

The rest of my code is pretty simillar to Class SettingPath code. I've only created a color picker instead of the FileChooser.

Where does the label at this position gets it's value? I haven't found it in the source code https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/settings.py

I'd also like to change the color of the text in that label to the currently selected color. How can I do this? But that's probably easy if I unterstand where the label is created.

And here is how it looks like if I click on the text 'BG color' (it's the ColorPicker that's included in Kivy):
[image: ColorPicker in action]

You can find the source code here:
https://gist.github.com/AWolf81/421976e65099d3e58a32

You can run it directly to see the described problem.

Answer (score 4):

OK, as expected the fix is pretty simple.

I've searched the Kivy files for SettingString and there I've found a kv file in C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\data\style.kv:

```
    731: <SettingString>:
    732:      Label:
    733:          text: root.value or ''
```

That's why it worked with the renamed class name. Just the KV definition was missing for the new type.

Adding the following lines fixed the issue:

```
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    Builder.load_string(
    '''
    <SettingColorPicker>:
        Label:
            text: root.value or ''
    ''')
```

I added these lines to the file where I've created the Class SettingColorPicker. You could probably add it to the 'style.kv' file directly. That should also work but I haven't tested it.

Coloring is also simple just use the root.value for the label color. Please notice that you have to convert it to a rgba tuple with kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex(root.value).

[image: Working example with coloring]